# How do I get user profile using Google Access Token

Tags: google-api, signing, google-oauth

i'm testing getting user information by google access token

http://www.mawk3y.net/glogin

after clicking sign in button i get redirected to

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=access_token_here

And get some JSON data like this

```
{
"issued_to": "my client id.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"audience": "my client id.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"user_id": "user id here",
"scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",
"expires_in": 3596,
"access_type": "online"
}
```

now i need to know how to extract user name , address and email any help please ?

thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token={access_token}

Answer (score 30):

I had the same issue. I wanted to extract the user information. But couldn't get the exact link to hit. Then I went through the code for [Passport Google Strategy](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth2/blob/master/lib/strategy.js) at `Line number 54`.

My scopes were `['profile', 'email']`

**GET** Request

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token={access_token}
```

Response

```
{
  "sub": "23423....",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "given_name": "John",
  "family_name": "Doe",
  "picture": "<Profile picture URL>",
  "email": "john.doe@gmail.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "locale": "en"
}
```

Comment: @RajatAggarwal I couldn't find this URL in google docs. So it took me so much time. Ultimately Passport JS codebase was of some help.

Comment: What is sub? is that like id?

Comment: @reza_khalafi the id is something like this: "112100881425580158538"

Comment: is there a url to validate an Access token with the Secret code ?

Answer (score 24):

Try this one:

```
 var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token={access_token}';

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    success: function(userInfo) {
      //info about user
      console.log(userInfo);
      console.log('test');
    },
    error: function(e) {
      console.log('error');

    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, That Worked

Comment: why doesn't Google documentation show that the access_token is supposed to be in the query string? https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/get

Comment: Yeah, that made me a little lost as well. They must mention it in some overview of the rest apis, but I couldn't find in the google plus section. I did find this though: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#callinganapi, which mentions that you can put it in the url or in the authorization header. But they aren't really related articles.

Comment: Why the access token is in get url params. Doesn't it poses security risks of getting logs in intermediary hops?

Comment: outdated version, V3 is out

Answer (score 19):

You can verify the auth token received after google signin on your server using this api

Request

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token={accces_token}
```

Response

```
{

  "email_verified": "true",
  "email": "abhinav.xxx@gmail.com",
  "name": "abhinav srivastava",
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-xgD_zFj1EgY/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAACZ0/fnecSQ03o0Y/s96-c/photo.jpg",
  "given_name": "abhinav",
  "family_name": "srivastava",
  "locale": "en",
  ...
  ...
}
```

[source](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth)

Comment: The above request is for id_token, not for access_token

Comment: instead of these url,You can use these url which gives name in response too,  https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?id_token={accces_token}

Comment: sometimes you don't have an id token and only have a access token

Answer (score 9):

If you want token_info, pass **tokeninfo** as param

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=ya29.a0AfH6SMArZZITzn-...
```

If you want all user info, pass **userinfo** as param

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?access_token=ya29.a0AfH6SMArZZITzn-...
```

**tokeninfo reponse**

```
{
    "azp": "",
    "aud": "",
    "sub": "",
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile openid",
    "exp": "",
    "expires_in": "",
    "email": "",
    "email_verified": "",
    "access_type": ""
}
```

**userinfo reponse**

```
{
    "sub": "",
    "name": "",
    "given_name": "",
    "family_name": "",
    "picture": "",
    "email": "",
    "email_verified": ,
    "locale": ""
}
```

Don't fogot to pass **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email** **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile** as scope

```
var params = {
  'client_id': '',
  'redirect_uri': '',
  'response_type': 'token',
  'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the access token (you get it in the redirect url) to access Google's People API. Check out the specs [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#obtaininguserprofileinformation).

You might find [Google's OAuth2 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) pretty useful to get an idea of how to use access tokens to access Google's APIs.

Good luck!

Comment: i get this error
{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg", "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.", "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console" } ], "code": 403, "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup." } }
when i create a http get to this url 
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me");
echo $response;

Comment: and when i use this code 
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/MY USER ID HERE?fields=birthday%2CcurrentLocation%2CdisplayName%2Cemails%2Cgender%2Cname&key={MY API KEY HERE}");
echo $response; 
i get this error 
{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "usageLimits", "reason": "keyInvalid", "message": "Bad Request" } ], "code": 400, "message": "Bad Request" } } 
and i just copied and pasted my updated API Key so i'm sure it's active

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Check [this](http://www.jensbits.com/2011/12/29/google-api-requests-with-oauth-2-0-access-token/). There is example with the demo</strike>

**Code Snippet:**

```
$accountObj = call_api($_SESSION['accessToken'],"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo");
```

`call_api` calls the API and gets the data:

```
function call_api($accessToken,$url){
    $curl = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    $curlheader[0] = "Authorization: Bearer " . $accessToken;
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curlheader);

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $responseObj = json_decode($json_response);

    return $responseObj;       
}
```

From the account object, the name can be accessed:

```
$your_name =  $accountObj->name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the quick start and see the sample here: [sample](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/javascript)

And here is a description of [People:get](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/get)

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple nodejs code at server side.

```
 var express = require('express');
 var appln = express();
 var google = require('googleapis');
 var plus = google.plus('v1');
 var OAuth = google.auth.OAuth2;
 var oauth2client = new OAuth(YOUR_CLIENT_ID  , YOUR_SECRET_ID ,  CALLBACK_REDIRECT_URI );

 appln.get("/tokens" , function(req , res ) {
         var code = req.query.code;
       oauth2client.getToken( code , function( err , tokens ){
                         if(err){
                            console.log(err);
                            res.send(err);
                            return;
                            }
                 oauth2client.setCredentials(tokens);
                 actoken = tokens.access_token;
                 reftoken = tokens.refresh_token;

       plus.people.get({  
                  userId: 'me',
                  auth: oauth2client
                  }, function (err, response) {
               // handle err and response
               var name = ""+response.displayName;
               var id =  ""+response.id;
               var age = ""+response.ageRange.min;
               if(err) console.log(err);
               console.log("Name : ", name," ",id,"",age);    
               res.send(response);

           });




        });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

[This is a ss of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5CAe.png) where we are sending a get request to the shown link with scopes specified.

Answer (score 0):

**IF YOU ARE USING PHP**

You can check [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth). In short, the code you are looking for is this

```
$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
```

Here payload has the info you need, as long as you add the needed scopes.