# how to verify google access token using node js

Tags: node.js, mongoose, backend, google-authentication

hi all i'm new in porgramming and i'm doing google auth along with login with email. i got the access token from google and i have no idea what to do next. PS login with email is working properly
here is my code where i'm getting accessToken from google,pleae help me

```
    module.exports = function (passport) {
        passport.use(
            new GoogleStrategy(
                {
                    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
                    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
                    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:4000/auth/google/callback',
                },
                async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
                    console.log(profile)
    
                    //get the user data from google
    
                    const newUser = {
                        googleId: profile.id,
                        userName: profile.displayName,
                        email: profile.emails[0].value,
                        imageUrl: profile.photos[0].value,
                        password: 'newuser',
                        isVerified: profile.emails[0].verified,
                        userToken: randomstring.generate()
                    }
```

Comment: your question is not clear what you want to do exactly,
but you can go through this medium article, you will get a proper clarity
https://medium.com/swlh/google-authentication-for-node-js-application-using-passport-678c8c068dd8

Comment: my question is when i click on signin with google , user successfully register in my database. but couldn't redirect to home screen . unauthorized error occur.

Comment: did you go through this medium article?

https://medium.com/swlh/google-authentication-for-node-js-application-using-passport-678c8c068dd8

Comment: yes but i couldn't get what i'm looking for

Comment: Once you have an access token from google, you are suppose to save it in a cookie. If access token is present, try to validate it by getting some user data, doesn't matter what. If it fails, then the access token is not valid. You do this check for every single page that you want to put behind a google signin.

Comment: @JM-AGMS this is what i don't know how to do it. can you please share some code . please i will be very thankful to you

Comment: This answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60506774