# Google userinfo endpoint You are receiving this error either because your input OAuth2 scope name is invalid or it refers to a newer scope

Tags: python, python-requests, google-api

I was trying to implement google login in my app. After user login my server receive code which i use to get token

```
    googleTokenEndpoint = os.getenv("GOOGLE_TOKEN_ENDPOINT")
    googleLoginTokenRequest = post(googleTokenEndpoint, data={
        "code": requestArgs["code"],
        "client_id": os.getenv("GOOGLE_LOGIN_CLIENT_ID"),
        "client_secret": os.getenv("GOOGLE_LOGIN_CLIENT_SECRET"),
        "redirect_uri": os.getenv("GOOGLE_LOGIN_CALLBACK_URL"),
        "grant_type": "authorization_code"
    })
    if not googleLoginTokenRequest.ok:
        return responseHandler.badGateway("Google token endpoint returned error: " 
                                          + str(json.loads(googleLoginTokenRequest.content)))
    googleLoginTokenJson = json.loads(googleLoginTokenRequest.content)
    if "error" in googleLoginTokenJson:
        return responseHandler.badGateway("Google token endpoint returned error: " + googleLoginTokenJson)
```

I was trying to use the token to get the user google account info

```
googleLoginUserinfoRequest = get(os.getenv("GOOGLE_SCOPE_USERINFO_ENDPOINT"), params={
            "access_token": googleLoginTokenJson["access_token"]
        })
print(googleLoginUserinfoRequest.content)
```

It prints the following message

```
b'You are receiving this error either because your input OAuth2 scope name is invalid 
or it refers to a newer scope that is outside the domain of this legacy API.\n\nThis 
API was built at a time when the scope name format was not yet standardized. 
This is no longer the case and all valid scope names (both old and new) are catalogued
at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes. Use that webpage to 
lookup (manually) the scope name associated with the API you are trying to call and use
it to craft your OAuth2 request.\n'
```

Here is the google endpoint url in my .env

```
GOOGLE_TOKEN_ENDPOINT = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
GOOGLE_SCOPE_USERINFO_ENDPOINT = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo"
GOOGLE_AUTHORIZATION_ENDPOINT = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"
```

Where did i go wrong and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

After some googling, found the answer at
[How do I get user profile using Google Access Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501895/how-do-i-get-user-profile-using-google-access-token)

The reason for the error above is that the userinfo endpoint is wrong, the correct one is https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo

So by setting this in .env

```
GOOGLE_SCOPE_USERINFO_ENDPOINT = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo"
```

The problem is fixed. Its so frustrating that the google login documentation https://developers.google.com/identity/openid-connect/openid-connect does not contain the endpoint to get userinfo using access token.